# How to Convert nested(Complex) JSON to excel IN Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, excel

Is there any way to convert complex json to Excel format?
For Example:

```
{ 
  "accounting" : [   
                     { "firstName" : "John",  
                       "lastName"  : "Doe",
                       "age"       : 23 }
                 ],                            
  "sales"      : [ 
                     { "firstName" : "Sally", 
                       "lastName"  : "Green",
                        "age"      : 27 }
                 ] 
}
```

Comment: Yes, there is.  Do a search of `VBA JSON Converter`, and there are plenty of usage examples on Stack Overflow.

Comment: i need in jquery. @RonRosenfeld

Comment: Sorry. Missed that requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Our company is using Kendo UI to create Excel documents in JavaScript. But it's not a free product. https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/excel/introduction

If link goes down.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.4.0/jszip.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<script>
var workbook = new kendo.ooxml.Workbook({
  sheets: [
    {
      // Column settings (width)
      columns: [
        { autoWidth: true },
        { autoWidth: true }
      ],
      // Title of the sheet
      title: "Customers",
      // Rows of the sheet
      rows: [
        // First row (header)
        {
          cells: [
            // First cell
            { value: "Company Name" },
            // Second cell
            { value: "Contact" }
          ]
        },
        // Second row (data)
        {
          cells: [
            { value: "Around the Horn" },
            { value: "Thomas Hardy" }
          ]
        },
        // Third row (data)
        {
          cells: [
            { value: "B's Beverages" },
            { value: "Victoria Ashworth" }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
});
kendo.saveAs({
    dataURI: workbook.toDataURL(),
    fileName: "Test.xlsx"
});
</script>
```

Comment: This should be a comment. Not an answer

Comment: I did not vote your answer down. Someone else did. I just wrote why I thought was the reason for the downvote.

Comment: Generally speaking, you should display an effort in explaining your answer in SO and avoid relying solely on external links. Because eventually, links might get broken in the future, and for someone who is looking for an answer to the same question, he might find a dead link.